# Flutter - RangeError(index)

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I get an error while I'm building a ListView. In this flutter app I try to count for each column some points when a button is clicked. But I'm getting always the same error.

> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE
>
> I/flutter (28729): The following RangeError was thrown while handling
> a gesture: I/flutter (28729): RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid
> value range is empty: 0

This is my code and I hope somebody is able to help me fixing the error:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class Punktezaehler extends StatefulWidget{

  final List<String> spieler_namen;
  Punktezaehler(this.spieler_namen);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _Punktezaehler(this.spieler_namen);
}


class _Punktezaehler extends State<Punktezaehler>{

  final List<String> spieler_namen;
  _Punktezaehler(this.spieler_namen);

  List<int> punkteanzahl_teamEins = [];
  List<int> punkteanzahl_teamZwei = [];

  int team1_hinzugezaehlt = 0;
  int team2_hinzugezaehlt = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    var spieler1 = spieler_namen[0].substring(0,3);
    var spieler2 = spieler_namen[1].substring(0,3);
    var spieler3 = spieler_namen[2].substring(0,3);
    var spieler4 = spieler_namen[3].substring(0,3);

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: new Text("$spieler1 & $spieler2 vs" +" $spieler3 & $spieler4"),
        actions: <Widget>[

        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
          child: new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.exposure_plus_2),
                      onPressed: () => punkte_hinzuzaehlen(1, 2)
                  )
                ],
              ),
              new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100.0)),
              new Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: punkteanzahl_teamEins.length, //--> Error is thrown here
                      itemBuilder: (context, index){
                        return Text(punkteanzahl_teamEins[index].toString());
                      }
                  ),
              ),
              new Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: punkteanzahl_teamZwei.length, //--> Error is thrown here
                      itemBuilder: (context, index){
                        return Text(punkteanzahl_teamZwei[index].toString());
                      }
                  ),
              ),
              new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.exposure_plus_2),
                      onPressed: () => punkte_hinzuzaehlen(2, 2)
                  )],
              )
            ],
          )
      ),
    );
  }

  void punkte_hinzuzaehlen(int team, int nummer){
    if (team == 1){
      setState(() {
        punkteanzahl_teamEins[team1_hinzugezaehlt] = nummer;
        team1_hinzugezaehlt++;
      });
    }
    else if(team == 2){
      setState(() {
        punkteanzahl_teamZwei[team2_hinzugezaehlt] = nummer;
        team2_hinzugezaehlt++;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem that when you click a button you are calling this line

```
punkteanzahl_teamEins[team1_hinzugezaehlt]
```

and `team1_hinzugezaehlt` have an initial value of `0` but every time the user click the button this value will increase by one 
so let's say your `punkteanzahl_teamEins` list contains 2 items in the fourth click the value `team1_hinzugezaehlt` will be 4 witch will cause this error . so the solution is to check whether the value is in the range or not

```
  if (team1_hinzugezaehlt<punkteanzahl_teamEins.length){
    setState(() {
      punkteanzahl_teamEins[team1_hinzugezaehlt] = nummer;
      team1_hinzugezaehlt++;
    });
  }
```

and do the same for the second function

Comment: Now the error is solved, but the function is now not even able to add values.

Comment: because you must add some values to  your punkteanzahl_teamEins list

Comment: List<int> punkteanzahl_teamEins = [1,4,5,7,8,9];

Comment: But isn't it possible to create a list that dynamically changes?

Comment: yes you can but i don't know what you really want to achieve

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I've found a solution by myself. The solution is to only say ".add" to the list.

Comment: glad to hear that